# Site works fine on localhost but resources don't load on AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I had an old personal website that was working fine but redid it. I cloned the repo to my AWS EC2 instance so that all files are replaced with my new site's. The site works fine when I launch it on localhost:8080, but when I run it on AWS, it shows only the HTML file but does not GET any of the resources. Here's my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const engines = require('consolidate');

app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/vendor', express.static(__dirname + '/vendor'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));


app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.render('index.html')
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server Started on http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('Press CTRL + C to stop server');
});
```

The server has everything in a src folder, which has server.js, views (index.html), img (all my images), css (css files), js (js files), vendor(some plugins).

I've tried accessing my resources the following ways in my index.html:

```
<link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="../../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="src/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I did what was logical first then just tried everything... nothing is working for me though.

When I hover over the errors in my developer console, I'm getting an error for:

```
GET http://example.com/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

I'm sure I'm making one little stupid mistake but I've been trying things for hours. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
No helpful responses yet, but I figured out what the problem was, just need to figure out how to fix it now.

When I originally launched my website I used an ubuntu process (can't remember which... that's the issue) that constantly ran node server.js. I terminated the old process the was running, and now the website doesn't show up at all (good progress though). Every time I kill the node process, it just restarts. Now I just need to figure out what the parent process is that is constantly launching this, kill it, and relaunch the server.

**EDIT 2**

Turns out I used pm2 to keep it running. Killed that process and restarted the server.

Comment: Please provide more information about the error that you are seeing. Is it 404 or something else? Any text associated with the error?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a 404 error. Sometimes the error is shown as : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), other times in the console it just has the red x and says GET example.com/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css. It seems like its an error with the path, but I've tried everything that I think makes sense. The server.js is in src. index.html is in views, so I need to go up one folder from views, then go into vendors (I think).

Comment: If I try to access http://example.com/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js it displays "Cannot GET /vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js". But shouldn't those file paths just be looking in the ubuntu EC2 filesystem for the vendor folder, bootstrap, etc? Instead of appending it to the URL?

Comment: @TravisM the web browser cannot look "in the ubuntu EC2 filesystem" It can only make requests to the web server, via URLs. The web browser does not have access to some remote server's file system. It sounds like you haven't configured your web server to actually serve those static files.

Comment: Hi @MarkB, Thanks for the response. I am using the same webserver as I was before when my site was working fine and serving static files correctly. Both the server.js, as well as my file structure are very similar to before. If you think it's an issue with the web server itself, do you think it best to call it a wash and start over from scratch? Thanks again.

Comment: People sometimes use forever (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to keep node scripts running.